# Too long website as footnote results in `Overfull \hbox`

Tags: footnotes, urls

I have a very long website as footnote and I get a warning message `Overfull \hbox`.

This is the website:

```
\footnote{Vgl.: http://www.bmwi.de/DE/Themen/Energie/Energiedaten-und-analysen/Energiedaten/energiegewinnung-energieverbrauch.html}
```

If I insert `allowbreak` like below, I get another warning message `Underfull \hbox`

```
\footnote{Vgl.: http://www.bmwi.de/DE/Themen/Energie/Energiedaten-und-analysen/Energiedaten/\allowbreak energiegewinnung-energieverbrauch.html}
```

Can someone tell me which is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried the `url` package? `\usepackage{url}...\url{http://www.long.path/here}`

Answer (score 6):

For long URLs use:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
...

\footnote{\raggedright Vgl.: \url{http://www.bmwi.de/DE/Themen/Energie/Energiedaten-und-analysen/Energiedaten/energiegewinnung-energieverbrauch.html}}
```

Comment: I would only do that if you're really really sure that the reader won't be irritated by the hyphen at the end of a line (like when you explain the line breaking behaviour at one point in the document). I think the author of the `url` package made a really smart choice when he decided not to allow line breaks after hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package that has special line breaking for URLs and also automatically adds a hyperlink to the PDF if you also use the `hyperref` package. Just pass your URL to the `\url` macro:

`\footnote{Vgl.: \url{http://www.bmwi.de/DE/Themen/Energie/Energiedaten-und-analysen/Energiedaten/energiegewinnung-energieverbrauch.html}}`

Comment: If I use this I get a too large space between Vgl.: and the beginning of the link, like shown here: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3622/glrperij_png.htm

Comment: @RStudent You probably also get the "underfull \hbox" error as you did for your manual fix. The sad truth is that there just aren't enough opportunities for line breaks to typeset this with a fixed line width. URLs are notoriously tricky here. What I would do in your case is to set the whole footnote as `\raggedright` or `\RaggedRight` (from the `ragged2e` package ... shouldn't do much of a different here).